# RestTemplate auto retry when JPA insert has error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I have an use case like this:

- I have a table named `user`, then I renamed it to `user_info`.
- I use `restTemplate.exchange(...)` to call external API to get user info then save it to my table

Everything worked well. But, when I rename `user` table to `user_info`, I got an error that `RestTemplate` auto retry call for 10 times although I don't configure anymore about `RestTemplate`.

I'm sorry for cannot show the log because of some reasons.
Here is scenario of logs on server:

- call external API successfully and got response data
- call  JPA to insert that response data to my table
- It show this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PALrq.png) (I know this error because I still put `@Table(name = "user")` in my code, I don't change its name yet).

Then it loop this scenario for 10 times. I cannot find how can it do this.

Please help me.

Thanks and sorry for my English if it's not clear.